# Events in Object variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-maintainability

Can you place a jQuery event inside of an object variable like so:

```
var taskObj = {
    buttonClick:function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            alert("Something");
        )};
    }
}
```

If so how would you call it the method? Could I possibly bind it to an event? Reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to change some spaghetti code (alot) and make it a bit easier to maintain without having to rewrite it all. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Your current object only has a click handler, so to actually bind it just run:

```
taskObj.buttonClick();
```

On DOM ready. To have an object hold the functions for handlers, you could do:

```
var taskObj = {
    buttonClick:function() {
        alert("Something");
    }
}
```

And define the handler as:

```
$("#button").click(taskObj.buttonClick);
```

Comment: Thank you! This will help me a great deal!